# Inject EJB into Eclipselink SessionCustomizer to provide Oracle schema name

Tags: java, oracle, eclipselink, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1

In a Java EE 6 application running on GlassFish (3.1.2.2b5), suppose you have a `ConfigurationService`, which reads some properties files and hands out property values accordingly:

```
@Local
public interface ConfigurationService { ... }
```

---

```
@Singleton  
public class ConfigurationServiceImpl implements ConfigurationService { ... }
```

There also is an Eclipselink `SessionCustomizer`, because the schema name of one of the persistence units (Oracle database) in the application needs to be programmatically set, i.e. be configurable from the properties files mentioned before. The `SessionCustomizer` is configured in a `persistence.xml` and the implementation contains a reference to the `ConfigurationService`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"...
    <persistence-unit name="myPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <property name="eclipselink.session.customizer" value="MySessionCustomizer"/>
        ...
```

---

```
public class MySessionCustomizer implements SessionCustomizer {
    @EJB
    private ConfigurationService configurationService;
    @Override
    public void customize(Session session) {
        session.getLogin().setTableQualifier(configurationService.getSchemaName());
        ...
```

Is it possible to have the `ConfigurationService` injected in such a way, so that it's available when the `SessionCustomizer` is instantiated? The above fails since the `ConfigurationService` instance is still null, i.e. the injection hasn't happened yet. This observation corresponds to the server's log entries. **It seems like the dependency injection mechanism is invariably started after the persistence units - and thus the `SessionCustomizer` - are instatiated.** I've messed around with various annotations (`@Startup`, `@DependsOn(...)`, ...) but to no avail. Is my conclusion correct or is there another way to have the EJB instantiated and injected sooner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the session customizer is created by EclipseLink (not by your container), the container is not responsible for injecting the dependencies.

Use JNDI lookup.